# How to write $\frac{1}{3\ln^23} + \frac{1}{4\ln^24} + \frac{1}{5\ln^25} +\dots$ as a short expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I have a snippet of series that I have to note as a short expression:

$$\frac{1}{3\ln^23} + \frac{1}{4\ln^24} + \frac{1}{5\ln^25} +\dots$$

I am not sure if it would be more reasonable to write it as follows:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+2)\ln^2(n+2)}$

or :

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}\,.$

Would it even make a difference?

Comment: No, it does not make a difference. If Wolfram alpha does not output a closed form , this would be a bad sign.

Comment: Great question. It doesn't matter, although your second option looks cleaner.

Comment: yeah, you can use the integral test to come up with an upper bound, but I doubt it has a good closed form.

Comment: By using numerical methods, we get that$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2(n)}=1.069058310\ldots$$

Comment: @FShrike, it is $f(0)$, **not** $f’’(0)$, indeed $f’’(z)=\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{n^z}n$ which diverges for $z=0$.

Comment: @Angelo I had the order of my thoughts mixed up. I was planning to say, if we can work out $f''(z)$ (which has no log term so could be easier) then we could infer $f$ from that (maybe). Here $f$ (from the now-deleted comment) is the map $z\mapsto\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{n^z}{n\cdot\ln^2n}$

Comment: @FShrike, $f’’(z)=\zeta(1-z)-1-\frac{2^z}2$ which is not defined for $z=0$, consequently, even if you manage to get a closed form for $f(z)$, you cannot evaluate it for $z=0$.

Comment: The value of $\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{1}{n\ln^2 n} = 2.109742801236...$ (which is $1/(2\ln^2 2)$ larger and includes the term $n=2$) is provided with high accuracy in https://oeis.org/A15563 .